# How to do a calculation using regex backreference in notepadpp?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a confiruation text file which follows a well-known pattern to attributing value to variables.

I want to increase the value of some of these variables by multiplying them to a constant value.

I first thought to do that with notepadd regex using backreference, but I didn't figure out how to do math operations with the backreference value in notepadpp. Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No that's not possible.

Comment: Well, you could do a few specific math operations - insert a zero after the number to multiply it by ten, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Do you have any suggestion for me here? Maybe there is a notepadpp plugin that allow scripting which I could do this? I'm looking for new ways to do this kind of task other than creating a whole desktop application just to do this.