# Alternative to do complex operations in text files using notepadpp?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I'm looking for a practical way to make complex operations in textual files.

From time to time I have the need to develop a whole application (usually in C++ or C#.Net) just to tweak textual configuration files (as .ini, .xml, .txt, etc).

Today I have the need to modify a .txt file with a well-known pattern of setting values to variables. I need to change the value of one specific variable (that appears many times in the file) by multiplying it for a constant (I first thought to use notepadpp + regex backreference but as I found in this thread: [How to do a calculation using regex backreference in notepadpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141651/how-to-do-a-calculation-using-regex-backreference-in-notepadpp) it seems to beimpossible).

Just when I thought to start developing another heavy desktop tool to accomplish this trivial task I thought if this is the way everyone smarter than me actually do this kind of thing. I thought there could be a notepadpp plugin that allow for complex operations in text using some kind of scripting language but I couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to investigate tools like `sed`, `awk` or even `python`.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: This Question is not appropriate to Stack Overflow. Asking for tools, libraries, plugins, etc. is specifically off-topic. Also, open-ended or wide-ranging discussions do not belong here, and should be put to discussion-oriented forums such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/. To ask for text manipulation tools, get very clear on your needs and criteria, then search and possibly post to the sister site, *Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*.

Comment: You may need to convert this question to more specific task you need to accomplish and include an example. Current questions as it is I marked as "too broad". And yes, you might want to use other effective tools to process your config files. (Including templating approach.)